# LookupError: Resource omw-1.4 not found

Tags: nltk, kaggle

I'm working on the Kaggle competition, 'Feedback Essay Evaluation'.
The competition rules require me to submit the notebook on Kaggle's notebook with internet acccess disabled.
I need to use the NLTK library for one of my feature extraction algorithms, but when I submit the notebook it throws this error:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource omw-1.4 not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('omw-1.4')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load corpora/omw-1.4

  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/opt/conda/nltk_data'
    - '/opt/conda/share/nltk_data'
    - '/opt/conda/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
```

I have tried to download the nltk packages and uploading them to the input dataset of Kaggle, but the kernel doesn't recognize the package. I tried overwriting and linking it to the uploaded package but it doesn't work.

How can I download omw-1.4 with internet access disabled?

Comment: You have to download the resource and install at the correct path where NLTK will search for it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and as explained in https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3024, you just need to download omw-1.4. Looks like that the new version of nlkt requires the presence of the omw-1.4 package, which was not needed in the past.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('omw-1.4')
```